# How to make React Material UI <Grid> 100% width

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, flexbox, material-ui

[image]

I am trying to make this Grid component width 100% so it covers the whole screen width.

## Javascript file

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Paper from '@material-ui/core/Paper';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import './CodingTest.css';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
  grid: {
    height: '100%',
    margin: '0px',
  },
  paper: {
    padding: theme.spacing(2),
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: theme.palette.text.secondary,
    background: theme.palette.success.light,
    height: '100%',
  },
}));

export default function CodingTest() {
  const classes = useStyles();

  return (
    <div>
      <Grid container className={classes.grid}>
        <Grid item xs={12} md={6}>
          <Paper className={classes.paper}>1</Paper>
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </div>
  );
}
```

Here is my .css file where I've managed to make it full width to the right but there still remains padding on the left as you can see from the picture above

## CSS

```
* {
  min-width: 100%;
}

.MuiContainer-root .MuiContainer-maxWidthLg {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border: 0px;
  min-width: 100%;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  .MuiContainer-root .MuiContainer-maxWidthLg {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}

@media (min-width: 1280px) {
  .MuiContainer-root .MuiContainer-maxWidthLg {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    min-width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
  }
}
```

Comment: at css if you use `100vw` the element would use 100% of view width.

Comment: @buzatto, I tried replacing every 100% to 100vh in the css and it did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I spun up a codesandbox with your code and inspected the html. I noticed this:
[image]

For me, the body of the page is adding 8px to the left. I added `style="margin: 0px;"` to the `body` tag in `index.html`.

```
  <body style="margin: 0px;">
```

Now it looks like:
[image]